# WYSIYG Editor won't fit inside Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a website and then I surfed the net for a WYSIWYG editor that's compatible with Bootstrap and I found one [here](https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) that I really like. So I tried to incorporate it into my modal window but it doesn't quite work as it's supposed to.

When I press the Activity Description tab, it looks like this:

[image]

It's like it ignores the boundaries of the Modal completely.

I don't quite understand this behaviour. The styling:

```
#editor {
    max-height: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); 
    padding: 4px; 
    /*box-sizing: content-box; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    overflow: scroll;
    outline: none;
}

div[data-role="editor-toolbar"] {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
/* http://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg */
/*global jQuery, $, FileReader*/
/*jslint browser:true*/
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var readFileIntoDataUrl = function (fileInfo) {
        var loader = $.Deferred(),
            fReader = new FileReader();
        fReader.onload = function (e) {
            loader.resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        fReader.onerror = loader.reject;
        fReader.onprogress = loader.notify;
        fReader.readAsDataURL(fileInfo);
        return loader.promise();
    };
    $.fn.cleanHtml = function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        return html && html.replace(/(<br>|\s|<div><br><\/div>|&nbsp;)*$/, '');
    };
    $.fn.wysiwyg = function (userOptions) {
        var editor = this,
            selectedRange,
            options,
            toolbarBtnSelector,
            updateToolbar = function () {
                if (options.activeToolbarClass) {
                    $(options.toolbarSelector).find(toolbarBtnSelector).each(function () {
                        var command = $(this).data(options.commandRole);
                        if (document.queryCommandState(command)) {
                            $(this).addClass(options.activeToolbarClass);
                        } else {
                            $(this).removeClass(options.activeToolbarClass);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            execCommand = function (commandWithArgs, valueArg) {
                var commandArr = commandWithArgs.split(' '),
                    command = commandArr.shift(),
                    args = commandArr.join(' ') + (valueArg || '');
                document.execCommand(command, 0, args);
                updateToolbar();
            },
            bindHotkeys = function (hotKeys) {
                $.each(hotKeys, function (hotkey, command) {
                    editor.keydown(hotkey, function (e) {
                        if (editor.attr('contenteditable') && editor.is(':visible')) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            execCommand(command);
                        }
                    }).keyup(hotkey, function (e) {
                        if (editor.attr('contenteditable') && editor.is(':visible')) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            getCurrentRange = function () {
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                    return sel.getRangeAt(0);
                }
            },
            saveSelection = function () {
                selectedRange = getCurrentRange();
            },
            restoreSelection = function () {
                var selection = window.getSelection();
                if (selectedRange) {
                    try {
                        selection.removeAllRanges();
                    } catch (ex) {
                        document.body.createTextRange().select();
                        document.selection.empty();
                    }

                    selection.addRange(selectedRange);
                }
            },
            insertFiles = function (files) {
                editor.focus();
                $.each(files, function (idx, fileInfo) {
                    if (/^image\//.test(fileInfo.type)) {
                        $.when(readFileIntoDataUrl(fileInfo)).done(function (dataUrl) {
                            execCommand('insertimage', dataUrl);
                        }).fail(function (e) {
                            options.fileUploadError("file-reader", e);
                        });
                    } else {
                        options.fileUploadError("unsupported-file-type", fileInfo.type);
                    }
                });
            },
            markSelection = function (input, color) {
                restoreSelection();
                if (document.queryCommandSupported('hiliteColor')) {
                    document.execCommand('hiliteColor', 0, color || 'transparent');
                }
                saveSelection();
                input.data(options.selectionMarker, color);
            },
            bindToolbar = function (toolbar, options) {
                toolbar.find(toolbarBtnSelector).click(function () {
                    restoreSelection();
                    editor.focus();
                    execCommand($(this).data(options.commandRole));
                    saveSelection();
                });
                toolbar.find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').click(restoreSelection);

                toolbar.find('input[type=text][data-' + options.commandRole + ']').on('webkitspeechchange change', function () {
                    var newValue = this.value; /* ugly but prevents fake double-calls due to selection restoration */
                    this.value = '';
                    restoreSelection();
                    if (newValue) {
                        editor.focus();
                        execCommand($(this).data(options.commandRole), newValue);
                    }
                    saveSelection();
                }).on('focus', function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (!input.data(options.selectionMarker)) {
                        markSelection(input, options.selectionColor);
                        input.focus();
                    }
                }).on('blur', function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.data(options.selectionMarker)) {
                        markSelection(input, false);
                    }
                });
                toolbar.find('input[type=file][data-' + options.commandRole + ']').change(function () {
                    restoreSelection();
                    if (this.type === 'file' && this.files && this.files.length > 0) {
                        insertFiles(this.files);
                    }
                    saveSelection();
                    this.value = '';
                });
            },
            initFileDrops = function () {
                editor.on('dragenter dragover', false)
                    .on('drop', function (e) {
                        var dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files && dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                            insertFiles(dataTransfer.files);
                        }
                    });
            };
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults, userOptions);
        toolbarBtnSelector = 'a[data-' + options.commandRole + '],button[data-' + options.commandRole + '],input[type=button][data-' + options.commandRole + ']';
        bindHotkeys(options.hotKeys);
        if (options.dragAndDropImages) {
            initFileDrops();
        }
        bindToolbar($(options.toolbarSelector), options);
        editor.attr('contenteditable', true)
            .on('mouseup keyup mouseout', function () {
                saveSelection();
                updateToolbar();
            });
        $(window).bind('touchend', function (e) {
            var isInside = (editor.is(e.target) || editor.has(e.target).length > 0),
                currentRange = getCurrentRange(),
                clear = currentRange && (currentRange.startContainer === currentRange.endContainer && currentRange.startOffset === currentRange.endOffset);
            if (!clear || isInside) {
                saveSelection();
                updateToolbar();
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.wysiwyg.defaults = {
        hotKeys: {
            'ctrl+b meta+b': 'bold',
            'ctrl+i meta+i': 'italic',
            'ctrl+u meta+u': 'underline',
            'ctrl+z meta+z': 'undo',
            'ctrl+y meta+y meta+shift+z': 'redo',
            'ctrl+l meta+l': 'justifyleft',
            'ctrl+r meta+r': 'justifyright',
            'ctrl+e meta+e': 'justifycenter',
            'ctrl+j meta+j': 'justifyfull',
            'shift+tab': 'outdent',
            'tab': 'indent'
        },
        toolbarSelector: '[data-role=editor-toolbar]',
        commandRole: 'edit',
        activeToolbarClass: 'btn-info',
        selectionMarker: 'edit-focus-marker',
        selectionColor: 'darkgrey',
        dragAndDropImages: true,
        fileUploadError: function (reason, detail) { console.log("File upload error", reason, detail); }
    };
}(window.jQuery));
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- WYSIWYG Editor Start -->
    <div class="form-control">
        <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title data-original-title="Font">
                    <span class="fa fa-font">A</span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="font-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <a data-edit="fontName Serif" style="font-family:'Serif'">Serif</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- other fonts...omitted to short the amount of text to read -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                   title="" data-original-title="Font Size">
                    <span class="fa fa-text-height"></span>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="" data-original-title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><span class="fa fa-bold"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="" data-original-title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><span class="fa fa-italic"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="" data-original-title="Strikethrough"><span class="fa fa-strikethrough"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="" data-original-title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><span class="fa fa-underline"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="" data-original-title="Bullet list"><span class="fa fa-list"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="" data-original-title="Number list"><span class="fa fa-list-ol"></span></a>
                <!-- TODO: Find an Indent Left Icon -->
                <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="" data-original-title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="" data-original-title="Indent (Tab)"><span class="fa fa-indent"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-info" data-edit="justifyleft" title="" data-original-title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><span class="fa fa-align-left"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="" data-original-title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><span class="fa fa-align-center"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="" data-original-title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><span class="fa fa-align-right"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="" data-original-title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><span class="fa fa-align-justify"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="" data-original-title="Hyperlink"><span class="fa fa-link"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
                    <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink">
                    <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
                </div>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="" data-original-title="Remove Hyperlink"><span class="fa fa-cut"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn" title="" id="pictureBtn" data-original-title="Insert picture (or just drag &amp; drop)"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span></a>
                <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 37px; height: 30px;">
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="" data-original-title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><span class="fa fa-undo"></span></a>
                <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="" data-original-title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><span class="fa fa-repeat"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- WYSIWYG Editor End -->
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I fixed the overflow problem where it appears on the wrong tab. It appears that the HTML had an "active" class on both the Activity Abstract and Description tabs.

Comment: What type of modal are you using?

Comment: @3.14159265358... He's using a Bootstrap modal.

Comment: I use `modal-dialog modal-lg` found in the Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it myself. I switched out this element:

```
<div class="form-control">
```

For this:

```
<div class="form-group">
```